# Is it Safe to write to linux Partition from Windows?

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows

I do tasks some of which require Windows while some require Ubuntu and thus I sometime need to access linux from windows, though the reverse is easily possible.

So, I searched in google and got an article: (http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) about accessing linux Partitions from Windows.

In  the Article it says that it might be messy to write using the software.

So, what can really go wrong if I do write or is it safe to write to a linux partition in such a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What can go wrong, is that you can lose files. It depends on the filesystem and how you access it, but in the worst case, you could lose access to all the data on your linux partition, although it would still be possible to recover - albeit difficult and very time consuming - with the proper tools. More likely is that you might just corrupt the file you write to, any maybe the ones on either side of it, and if you're very unlucky any subdirectories. As a rule of thumb, I would say go ahead and write whatever you want, but make sure that a) you have a backup before you start, and b) you check the integrity of the filesystem after writing.

A better alternative for you would be to format the partition ntfs, which linux can read/write to, and which is the native format for windows. As you know, it is easy to mount windows partitions under linux, so why not just write to your windows partition, and then copy over whatever you need when you boot up with linux?

Comment: +1 for formatting the partition as NTFS: it's the simplest way if you need to read/write it in both OSes.

Comment: So, If I format the partition mounted at '/' during installation as NTFS will ubuntu run properly and will also allow easy sharing of files??

Comment: @TapanAnand Unfortunately, I don't think you can mount an ntfs partition as / or /home. I would suggest making a small ext partition (you only need a few hundred megabytes) to boot from, and then just storing all your files in a separate partition, ideally formatted fat32 as that is more reliable for daily access than ntfs.

Comment: OK looks like a good solution. Will try it next time I install Ubuntu.